# Is it known if the Scimitar can charge and/or fire its thalaron weapon while cloaked?

Tags: star-trek, romulan, cloaking, star-trek-nemesis

The Remus Warbird Scimitar had what is commonly referred to as a "perfect" cloaking device which is one that allows the vessel to fire weapons while cloaked. It also had an additional unique armament in the thalaron radiation weapon, which required a not-insignificant amount of time and ship reconfiguration in order to fire.

Do we know if the Scimitar was capable of charging or even out-right firing the thalaron radiation weapon while maintaining the cloak?

Comment: Given that it took 7 minutes to charge, I'd imagine they could at least charge it while cloaked.  Don't know about firing it, but I don't see why not.

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure it's that easy. Most source material we have on cloaking usually mentions how carefully the ship needs to control energy emissions or not having the available power while cloaked and the like. But the ship changing it's physical configuration and charging something could be clear examples of the ship doing "too much" while cloaked. I'm looking for a source that confirms this, which I suspect will only be found in print some place, if it even exists.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there is good information on this. It's open to interpretation. It's never explicitly said you can use the thalaron weapon from being cloaked in the script and since this is a unique ship to 'Star Trek Nemesis' I don't think you can definitely say if it is or isn't possible. But, here's my answer.

> LAFORGE: Captain, there is something else. I was reviewing the sensor logs. Look at this! When the Scimitar decloaked there was a momentary spike in the tertiary EM band. There! ...You're not going to believe this. It's thalaron.

This line implies that even though their cloak is perfect like Geordi says it's discharging thalaron radiation. 
This line could also just be a plot device to give some foreshadowing and raise tension about the scary radiation. 
Then again, it could mean that cloaking keeps this type of radiation in and stores it really well. Which makes me believe that the thalaron intermix that they show later in the movie near the climax would overload the cloak.

Though I bet they could charge it up a little before they needed to vent this radiation and drop cloak since the radiation didn't ever mess with the cloaking device once. This is also assuming this cloak follows the rules of other cloaking devices that need to be dropped for venting radiation build ups.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they could fire weapons and everything else while cloaked, so I presume so. That seemed to be implied as the plan to attack Earth ( I doubt even the Scimitar would survive being attacked by all the ships right at Earth while charging for 7 minutes.) So, it is reasonable to assume he can at least charge while cloaked, and as for FIRING while cloaked well... likely doesn't matter, you are dead then anyway.